# Why do I get two different answers for finding the area of the inner loop of a polar function?

Tags: calculus

inner loop of $1+2\cos\theta$

Integral I: $2(1/2)\int_{2\pi/3}^{\pi} (1+2\cos\theta)^2 d\theta = \frac{2\pi - 3\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Integral II: $(1/2)\int_{2\pi/3}^{4\pi/3} (1+2\cos\theta)^2 d\theta = \pi -\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}$

Integral I: is just doubling the bottom half of the area of the inner loop.

Integral II:is the entire loop.

Why do I get half the value for using the whole area?

Comment: What is 'inner loop'? Are you saying the two values are not the same?

Comment: (2 Pi) / 2 = Pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the same value for both integrals! I don't see what the issue seems to be...

Comment: just spent too much time doing homework, and was checking some of the answers. Should sleep.